# On change of value in datetimepicker it should update another text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and trying to use it and I am trying to do below mentioned.

**My datetime picker control 1**

```
<div class='input-group date' id="reportdate">
                <input type='text' class="form-control"  value="@Model.ReportDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

**My  date time picker control 2**

```
<div class='input-group date' id="fromdate">
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" value="@Model.RecievedFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

**What I am trying to do?**

On change of the value from my date time picker control 1 it should change the value in datetimepiker control2.

**What I did?**

My main.js class which is handling all these functions.

```
var main = main || {};

main.functions = function() {

function changeDates() {
  ***// I am trying to change the value of my datetime picker control2 here.
   var val = $(this).val;
    alert(val);***
}

return {
    changeDates: changeDates
};
}();


main.Loader = function () {
//-- Entry point
function init() {
    var $body = $("body");
    loadDatePickers($body);
    loadTimePickers($body);

}

//-- Load date time pickers
function loadDatePickers($context) {
    var $datePickers = $context.find(".date");
    if ($datePickers.length) {
        $datePickers.each(function () {
            $(this).datetimepicker({ language: 'en-gb', pickTime: false });
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "reportdate") {
                $(this).change(function () {
                    main.functions.changeDates();
                });
            }

        });
    }
}

function loadTimePickers($context) {
    var $timePickers = $context.find(".time");
    if ($timePickers.length) {
        $timePickers.each(function () {
            $timePickers.datetimepicker({ language: 'en-gb', pickDate: false });
        });
    }
}



return {
    init: init
};
 }();

 $(document).ready(function () {
main.Loader.init();
 });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.change` event for that,

```
$("#reportdate").find(".form-control").change(function () {
    $("#fromdate").find(".form-control").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: It is hitting and replacing with null in my fromdate.